# Computing the expected value of a function of a binomially distributed r.v

Tags: matlab, approximation, probability-theory, binomial-cdf

I'm trying to compute the expected value of a **function of X**, where `X` is binomially distributed. So I want to compute something on the form of `sum(Pr(X=k)*f(k),k=0,..,n)`. Now I want to see if the value converges as the binomial tree increases, i.e. if `n` increases. However, for increasing `n`, the (`n` over `k`) term in `Pr(X=k)` goes to infinity for some `k`, whereas the function `f(k)=0`, this gives a multiplication of `Inf*0` which produces `NaN` in matlab. Hence the result is `NaN`.

However, by computing the analogous problem in matrix form, I know the expected value should converge.

So my question is, how can I deal with this?

This is the code I've got so far (for some parameters, `u~d~0.5. K=s=100`)

```
sum=0;
for k=0:N;
    tmp=exp(-r*T)*nchoosek(N,k)*q_u^k*(1-q_u)^(N-k)*max(s*u^k*d^(N-k)-K,0);
    sum=sum+tmp;
end
```

Comment: You may have numerical precission issues from computing `nchoosek(N,k)` (very large) and multiplying by `q_u^k` (very small). Use [`binopdf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/binopdf.html) instead